# Intellij IDEA plugin with markers

Tags: intellij-idea

We use framework where for some classes there is xml configuration file. I want to write plugin which adds icon near field declaration (in eclipse that icons are called markers). When click on this icon user navigate to xml configuration for the field. This is similar to spring or hibernate plugin with xml config. How can I add that markers? Is there some open source plugin that do similar things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition [source code from GitHub](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community) if don't have it already.

Please see `com.intellij.navigation.GotoRelatedProvider`, sample implementation can be found in `com.theoryinpractice.testng.TestNGRelatedFilesProvider`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is what I needed. But how and when GotoRelatedProvider is invoked? I created plugin, in plugin.xml added gotoRelatedProvider with my implementation MyGotoRelatedProvider and this class is never invoked when I run plugin.

Comment: See `com.intellij.ide.actions.GotoRelatedFileAction`.