# IntelliJ: Jump to a class based on the name of the current class

Tags: intellij-idea, navigation

I'd like to know if it is possible in IntelliJ IDEA to jump to a class based on the name of the class I am currently in. I want to bind a key to this action.

**Example:**
I am in class FooBar and want to jump to FooBarHandler

*If this is only possible via a plugin. I'd appreciate a link to a documentation that could give me a head start.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such custom action. You can check the examples of the `com.intellij.navigation.GotoRelatedProvider` class in [IntelliJ IDEA Community sources](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community).

Also see the [IntelliJ IDEA SDK documentation](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/welcome.html) and this answer: [Intellij IDEA plugin with markers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13129832/2000323). Feel free to [ask specific questions](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/getting-help.html#problems-with-code-support-issues) on [Plugin developers Forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development) or in [#intellij-platform JetBrains Platform Slack community](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/slack/).